# Having trouble deleting a row from a table in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am having trouble deleting a row from a table in SQL. The schema's name is 'imageusers'. Inside 'imageusers' there is a table named 'images' which has three columns: imageID, username and image but I'll be ignoring the image column as I can delete the row without making a preparedstatement for that one's info.

My code:

```
myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imageusers?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&relaxAutoCommit=true", "user", "password");

String update =  ("DELETE FROM images WHERE imageID = ?, username = ?");


PreparedStatement preparedStatement = myConn.prepareStatement(update);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "image name");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "username");

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I have double checked everything. The myConn connection is valid. The image name and username strings are valid and exist in the sql table.

But when I try to run it I get the following error:

> "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE imageID =
>   'image name', username = 'username'' at line 1.

I looked online and this is the correct way to delete a row from sql in JDBC is it not? Every example I saw did it like this. I am running MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You need to use 'and' instead of a comma in the where clause: Where imageID = ? and username = ?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off, this

```
String update =  ("DELETE FROM images WHERE imageID = ?, username = ?");
```

should be using `AND` instead of `,` - like

```
String update =  "DELETE FROM images WHERE imageID = ? AND username = ?";
```